# JS, Recursion, Function Stack Example, Hard to Understand

Tags: javascript, recursion

Below is an example from MDN [Function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#function_scope). I can not understand how the `end: 0` and the rest of `end:`  are printed. I was expecting that the `console.log("end: " + i);` will never be reached.

```js
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0) return;
  console.log("begin: " + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log("end: " + i);
}
foo(3);
```

Output:

```
begin: 3
begin: 2
begin: 1
begin: 0
end: 0
end: 1
end: 2
end: 3
```

Comment: In the middle of `foo()`  is a call to itself (making this a recursive function).  Everything after that call does not execute until the if condition becomes true and returns. The stack unwinds and now calls everything after the internal `foo()` executes.  It is extremely important to make sure recursive functions have a terminating condition.

Comment: *I was expecting that the `console.log("end: " + i);` will never be reached.* - why would you think that? it's just the next step, which is not conditioned on anything

Comment: Incidentally, you would be correct that it would never be reached...*IF* there were no terminating condition.  The calls would continue until your program crashed due to...well...a stack overflow :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, the reason I was thinking it will never reach the second console.log was because the the recursive call was just before it and the function return was the first statement. Hence I thought that once the condition for return is met then it will return and never reach the second console.log. The detailed replies by Steve and Henrik helped me to see that the full flow of the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to all recursion is the exit condition. Without it the function will run forever or the system runs out of memory. The exit condition for `foo` is `if (i < 0) return;`.
Now because javascript is, in this case at least, run synchronously, it will finish whatever it is doing before moving on to the next line of code.

The function calls itself with `foo(i - 1);` which will in turn call itself and so on until the exit condition is met. It is therefore vital that the exit condition is placed before the recursive call.

To make this easier to understand, consider the value of `i` for each successive call:

```
foo(3)
  foo(2)
    foo(1)
      foo(0) // exit condition is met, ending the recursion
      print end 0
    print end 1
  print end 2
print end 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were to write:

```
console.log("begin");
my_custom_function(1);
console.log("end")
```

Then `console.log` will log begin, then `my_custom_function` will be called, and when `my_custom_function` has finished it will pick up where it left off and `console.log` will log end.

It's exactly the same.

When `foo` has finished, it will return to the calling function (which happens to also be `foo`) and continue where it left off.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it in blocks. Below I added each step showing the actual `i` values and indenting it on each recursion. You can see that after the recursion is done, then it will finish the function call on each of the previous blocks.

```js
foo(3) {
    if (3 < 0) return;
    console.log("begin: " + 3);
    foo(3-1) {
        if (2 < 0) return;
        console.log("begin: " + 2);
        foo(2-1) {
            if (1 < 0) return;
            console.log("begin: " + 1);
            foo(1-1) {
                if (0 < 0) return;
                console.log("begin: " + 0);
                foo(0-1){
                    if (-1 < 0) return; // Exit recursion
                }
                console.log("end: " + 0);
            }
            console.log("end: " + 1);
        }
        console.log("end: " + 2);
    }
    console.log("end: " + 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo() {
  if (i < 0) {
console.log("end: " + i);
clearInterval(lauch);//close the interval
} else { // with an else
  console.log("begin: " + i);
 i -= 1;
}
  
}

var i = 3;//global var
var lauch;
start();

function start () {
 lauch = setInterval(foo, 1000); // 1 sec or 1000 millisecondes, the function reaload
}
```

Maybe is this you looking for ?